# C Programming Return (!int) when int return value expected?

Tags: c

```
int isEmptyArray (struct arrayBagStack * b) {
  return(!b->count);
}
```

I have this code snippet that is shown as a correct answer.  I do not understand the concept that is shown of returning a (!) Not Int value when the Int value is expected.  Can someone explain why this would work and what is the expected behavior?

`count` is a int member variable of `struct arrayBagStack`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no change of type happening here.

The not operator (`!`) simply computes another integer value, which is then returned.

In this case, it's being used to convert the count into a true/false value to answer the question whether the array is empty. If `b->count` is 0, `!0` is `1`, which means "true". If it's any other value, `!` will convert that to `0`, i.e. "false".

In my opinion code like this fails to be optimally clear; it should just be:

```
return b->count != 0;
```

Which generates the exact same values for all values of `count`, but is way clearer.

Answer (score 3):

the return value is playing the role of a boolean, if `count` is `0` return `1`, otherwise return `0`

Answer (score 3):

- In C, *zero* `0` is treated as *boolean* `false`.
- Any other *non zero* value is *boolean* `true`.
- By default `true` means `1`.

So when you `return(!b->count)` which is equivalent to `b->count ! = 0` return either `true` or `false`. But as the `return` type is `int` then if `b->count` is equal to `0` then `isEmptyArray` will return `1`, `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of what you're returning.

isEmptyArray means

- a return of "true" says the array is empty
- a return of "false" says
  the array is not

So if b -> count is NULL, then you'd want to return true for empty, so you inverse it

and if b -> count is not NULL you want to return false for not empty, so you inverse it

If you wanted to remove the !, then rename the function to isNotEmptyArray to follow the logic

Answer (score 2):

Its not that it will change the datatype from `int` to `!int`.

`!` will work on the value of `b->count`. So if it is 0, `!b->count` will result in `1`, otherwise `0`.